# Not a GROUP BY expression error

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm relatively new to databases. I am using Oracle and I'm trying to implement this query to find the number of personal training sessions the member has had.

The tables are;

**MEMBERS**

```
MEMBERS_ID(NUMBER),
MEMBERSHIP_TYPE_CODE(VARCHAR),
ADDRESS_ID(NUMBER), CLUB_ID(NUMBER) 
MEMBER_NAME(VARCHAR), 
MEMBER_PHONE(VARCHAR), 
MEMBER_EMAIL(VARCHAR)
```

**PERSONAL_TRAINING_SESSIONS**

```
SESSION_ID(VARHCAR), 
MEMBER_ID (NUMBER), 
STAFF_ID(VARCHAR), 
SESSION_DATETIME(DATE)
```

My query is returing this error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

```
SELECT MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID,MEMBERS.MEMBER_NAME, COUNT(personal_training_sessions.session_id)
FROM MEMBERS JOIN personal_training_sessions
ON personal_training_sessions.member_id=members.member_id
GROUP BY personal_training_sessions.session_id;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have looked around do I need to separate the count query?

Comment: I would highly recommend going through a tutorial and having a play with some selects to see what is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says it all, you're not grouping by `MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID` and `MEMBERS.MEMBER_NAME`.

```
SELECT MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID, MEMBERS.MEMBER_NAME
     , COUNT(personal_training_sessions.session_id)
  FROM MEMBERS 
  JOIN personal_training_sessions
    ON personal_training_sessions.member_id = members.member_id
 GROUP BY MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID, MEMBERS.MEMBER_NAME
```

You want the count of personal sessions *per* member, so you need to group by the member information.

The basic (of course it can get a lot more complex) GROUP BY, SELECT query is:

```
SELECT <column 1>, <column n>
     , <aggregate function 1>, <aggregate function n>
  FROM <table_name>
 GROUP BY <column 1>, <column n>
```

An aggregate function being, as Ken White says, something like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT()` etc. You GROUP BY *all* the columns that are not aggregated.

This will only work as intended if your `MEMBERS` table is unique on `MEMBER_ID`, but based on your query I suspect it is. To clarify what I mean, if your table is not unique on `MEMBER_ID` then you're not counting the number of sessions per `MEMBER_ID` but the number of sessions per `MEMBER_ID` *and* per `MEMBER_NAME`. If they're in a 1:1 relationship then it's effectively the same thing but if you can have multiple `MEMBER_NAME`s per `MEMBER_ID` then it's not.

Comment: +1. To clarify, the `GROUP BY` should contain all the columns that are not aggregated (not part of a `SUM()`, `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or other aggregate function).

Comment: I've just added a little thing like that @KenWhite :-).

Comment: I see that, but I'm not sure that it clearly explains; someone new to SQL might not know that `<column 1>, <column n>` means `all the columns that are not aggregated`.

Comment: Another tip: if you find that you have a great many elements in the GROUP by clause in a query like this (for example you have a lot of columns in the MEMBERS table that you are including) then you could place the aggregation of the personal_training_session data in an inline view or common table expression, grouping by member_id, and then join this pre-aggregated result to the members table. This can be much faster with large data sets, particularly if your instance is tuned for OLTP queries with a low PGA memory allocation, as it can save the sort from spilling to disk.

Comment: Thank you for making me smile @DavidAldridge, this is why I love SO!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID,
       MEMBERS.MEMBER_NAME, 
       COUNT(personal_training_sessions.session_id)

FROM MEMBERS JOIN personal_training_sessions
ON personal_training_sessions.member_id=members.member_id

GROUP BY personal_training_sessions.session_id;
```

You are using a COUNT function, thus the other columns, MEMBER_ID & MEMBER_NAME, must be included in the group by clause.