# How correct query for group by when joining table using left join

Tags: sql, join, group-by

This query keeps returning the error:

> not a GROUP BY expression

Can someone please help me correct my query? I'm not good at joining tables.

```
select distinct(nama), namabapa, data_saranabapa.nokpbapa, namaibu, data_saranaibu.nokpibu
from ((data_semua_murid
      left join data_saranabapa on data_semua_murid.nokpbapa=data_saranabapa.nokpbapa)
      left join data_saranaibu on data_semua_murid.nokpibu=data_saranaibu.nokpibu)
where kodsekolah='WBA0002'
group by namabapa
order by namabapa asc
```

Comment: you need to group by : nama,namabapa, data_saranabapa.nokpbapa, namaibu, data_saranaibu.nokpibu....see this post::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962772/not-a-group-by-expression-error

Comment: DISTINCT is NOT a function on a column, it works on the whole selected rows. select distinct(nama), namabapa... eq select distinct nama, namabapa... eq select distinct nama, (namabapa)...

Comment: Which dbms is this? The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must group by all the columns you select in your query

```
select distinct(nama), namabapa, data_saranabapa.nokpbapa, namaibu, data_saranaibu.nokpibu
from ((data_semua_murid
      left join data_saranabapa on data_semua_murid.nokpbapa=data_saranabapa.nokpbapa)
      left join data_saranaibu on data_semua_murid.nokpibu=data_saranaibu.nokpibu)
where kodsekolah='WBA0002'
group by nama, namabapa, data_saranabapa.nokpbapa, namaibu, data_saranaibu.nokpibu
order by namabapa asc
```