# how can i get max value for each country

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm using oracle sql developer. i have two tables

transactions:

```
╔════╤═══════╗
║ id │ value ║
╠════╪═══════╣
║ 1  │ 10    ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 1  │ 20    ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 2  │ 30    ║
╟────┼───────╢
║ 3  │ 40    ║
╚════╧═══════╝
```

and users:

```
╔════╤═════════╤═════╗
║ id │ country │ sex ║
╠════╪═════════╪═════╣
║ 1  │ Germany │ m   ║
╟────┼─────────┼─────╢
║ 2  │ Germany │ f   ║
╟────┼─────────┼─────╢
║ 3  │ France  │ m   ║
╚════╧═════════╧═════╝
```

i want to get max value for each country like this

```
╔════╤═════════╤═════╤══════════╗
║ id │ country │ sex │ maxvalue ║
╠════╪═════════╪═════╪══════════╣
║ 2  │ Germany │ f   │ 30       ║
╟────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────╢
║ 3  │ France  │ m   │ 40       ║
╚════╧═════════╧═════╧══════════╝
```

i know how to get max value for each user and join tables

```
SELECT u.*, max
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id, max(value) as max
FROM transactions 
group by ID) t
on u.id = t.id;
```

what should i change to get a max value for each country?

Comment: Where is Germany m ?

Comment: what will be the expected output if the values were 20, 30 for id = 1 in transactions table? Will it replace France to Germany?

Comment: it should shows both

Comment: Id 1 value is also 30 (10 + 20). So, id 1 and id 2 max values are same. So, what now? why do we choose 2 or 1?

Comment: only one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
select tmp.country, tmp.maxvalue, tmp.id, users.sex from (
select users.country as country, max(transactions.value) as maxvalue, max(users.id) as id 
from users
inner join transactions on users.id = transactions.id
group by users.country) tmp
inner join users on tmp.id = users.id;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f476/27/0

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
SELECT id, country, sex, value AS maxvalue FROM (
    SELECT u.id, u.country, u.sex, COALESCE(t.value, 0) AS value
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY u.country ORDER BY t.value DESC NULLS LAST ) AS rn
      FROM users u LEFT JOIN transactions t
        ON u.id = t.id
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

This will get all the values for each country and rank them, then retrieve only the one with the top rank. If you want to get ties as well then use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id, country, sex, value AS maxvalue FROM (
    SELECT u.id, u.country, u.sex, COALESCE(t.value, 0) AS value
         , RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY u.country ORDER BY t.value DESC NULLS LAST ) AS rn
      FROM users u LEFT JOIN transactions t
        ON u.id = t.id
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional method would not use a subquery, but simply `join` and `group by`:

```
SELECT u.country, MAX(t.value)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     transactions t
     ON u.id = t.id
GROUP BY u.country;
```

Comment: May be OP wants to group also by `sex`. The sample expected data don't match with text explanation.

Comment: your code works but only when i want to show country and max value, when i want to show country, max value and sex i got an error -
"Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression""

Comment: hi @gordonLinoff, I told to you ;)

Comment: i dont want to group by sex but i want to show it in a table

Comment: yes, funny. I'm expecting the end of this thread. I go for popcorn.

Answer (score 1):

This might get the required result

```
SELECT u.id, u.country, u.sex, MAX(t.value)
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON u.id = t.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.country, u.sex;
```

Comment: your code its not working, it doesnt shows maxvalue for each country

Comment: my query showing max value for **country** and **sex**, if you want only country wise value than remove u.id and u.sex from both the select and group by clause

Comment: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: This error occurs when you don't have all the fields of selected clause in group by clause while using an aggregate function. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962772/not-a-group-by-expression-error)

Comment: my real table is much bigger and i have there more than 2 sexes

Comment: so what? more than two sexes and table size (rows in table) does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first find the max per country and the do another join for the sex, like this:

```
SELECT u.*, t.value
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN users u ON t.id = u.id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT us.country, MAX(tr.value) AS max_value
 FROM transactions tr
 INNER JOIN users us ON tr.id = us.id
 GROUP BY us.country) sub ON t.value = sub.value AND u.country = sub.country
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
SELECT t.ID, u.COUNTRY, T.VALUE, 
row_number() over(partition by u.country order by t.value desc) rn
FROM USERS u , transactions t
where u.id = t.id)
where rn = 1
```